# How is a JSON object made into an array using JQ?

Tags: json, linux, bash, unix, jq

The following has been performed on  [this JSON file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openwrt/packages/openwrt-19.07/net/adblock/files/adblock.sources):

**INPUT**

```sh
 jq 'with_entries(select([.key] | inside(["adaway", "adguard", "disconnect", "yoyo"])))' adblock.sources
```

**OUTPUT**

```json
{
  "adaway": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AdAway/adaway.github.io/master/hosts.txt",
    "rule": "/^127\\.0\\.0\\.1[[:space:]]+([[:alnum:]_-]{1,63}\\.)+[[:alpha:]]+([[:space:]]|$)/{print tolower($2)}",
    "size": "S",
    "focus": "mobile",
    "descurl": "https://github.com/AdAway/adaway.github.io"
  },
  "adguard": {
    "url": "https://adguardteam.github.io/AdGuardSDNSFilter/Filters/filter.txt",
    "rule": "BEGIN{FS=\"[/|^|\\r]\"}/^\\|\\|([[:alnum:]_-]{1,63}\\.)+[[:alpha:]]+[\\/\\^\\r]+$/{print tolower($3)}",
    "size": "L",
    "focus": "general",
    "descurl": "https://adguard.com"
  },
  "disconnect": {
    "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/lists.disconnect.me/simple_malvertising.txt",
    "rule": "/^([[:alnum:]_-]{1,63}\\.)+[[:alpha:]]+([[:space:]]|$)/{print tolower($1)}",
    "size": "S",
    "focus": "general",
    "descurl": "https://disconnect.me"
  },
  "yoyo": {
    "url": "https://pgl.yoyo.org/adservers/serverlist.php?hostformat=nohtml&showintro=0&mimetype=plaintext",
    "rule": "/^([[:alnum:]_-]{1,63}\\.)+[[:alpha:]]+([[:space:]]|$)/{print tolower($1)}",
    "size": "S",
    "focus": "general",
    "descurl": "https://pgl.yoyo.org"
  }
}
```

---

I'd like to have it be an array, and have tried recommendations like piping it into `jq -s '.'`. These attempts only yield a single-element array. What would be the best way to format this? I highly suspect `from_entries` and `to_entries` have to be incorporated somehow.

---

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```json
[
  {
    "key": "adaway",
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AdAway/adaway.github.io/master/hosts.txt",
    "rule": "/^127\\.0\\.0\\.1[[:space:]]+([[:alnum:]_-]{1,63}\\.)+[[:alpha:]]+([[:space:]]|$)/{print tolower($2)}",
    "size": "S",
    "focus": "mobile",
    "descurl": "https://github.com/AdAway/adaway.github.io"
  },
  {
    "key": "adguard",
    "url": "https://adguardteam.github.io/AdGuardSDNSFilter/Filters/filter.txt",
    "rule": "BEGIN{FS=\"[/|^|\\r]\"}/^\\|\\|([[:alnum:]_-]{1,63}\\.)+[[:alpha:]]+[\\/\\^\\r]+$/{print tolower($3)}",
    "size": "L",
    "focus": "general",
    "descurl": "https://adguard.com"
  },
  {
    "key": "disconnect",
    "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/lists.disconnect.me/simple_malvertising.txt",
    "rule": "/^([[:alnum:]_-]{1,63}\\.)+[[:alpha:]]+([[:space:]]|$)/{print tolower($1)}",
    "size": "S",
    "focus": "general",
    "descurl": "https://disconnect.me"
  },
  {
    "key": "yoyo",
    "url": "https://pgl.yoyo.org/adservers/serverlist.php?hostformat=nohtml&showintro=0&mimetype=plaintext",
    "rule": "/^([[:alnum:]_-]{1,63}\\.)+[[:alpha:]]+([[:space:]]|$)/{print tolower($1)}",
    "size": "S",
    "focus": "general",
    "descurl": "https://pgl.yoyo.org"
  }
]
```

Comment: An array of objects? Can you show an example of your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As implied in a comment, there are several ways of interpreting the question as originally asked, but the three main interpretations could be realized by adding one of the following to your jq filter:

```
| [keys_unsorted[] as $key | {$key} + .[$key] ]
```

or

```
| map(.)
```

or:

```
| [keys_unsorted[] as $key | { $key): .[$key] } ]
```

Update: The first of these is the one corresponding to the shown expected output. `{$key}` is shorthand for `{"key": $key}`.

Comment: I've added some expected output for clarity